# Make sure that the last http post reaches back-end last in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, httpclient

How could I make sure that the last http post reaches back-end last in Angular?

My use case. I have a simple implemented by me chip list. It is represented by chips and an input at the end. When user types something into the input and presses the `Enter` then a chip with the typed text is added to the chip list, also user can remove a specific chip from the list. On both the addition and removal I am updating the chip list on the back-end. Here is the piece of code responsible for this.

```js
addNewChip() {
    if(this.chipText) {
        this.chips.push(this.chipText);
        this.chipText = "";
        this.updateChipsOnBE();
    }
}

removeChip(chipText) {
    this.chips = this.chips.filter(text => text !== chipText);
    this.updateChipsOnBE();
}

private updateChipsOnBE(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.chipAPI.update(this.BEAddress, this.chips);
}
```

Now I am worried about the possible race condition: the `this.chipAPI.update` operation may not yet be completed on BE, while another `this.chipAPI.update` operation will be triggered in such a way, that the latter operation will complete before the former. That would mean, that a user would lose the last change he or she applied.

I am feeling that there is should be a way in RxJS to prevent it, but I can not neither find nor come up with a solution.

Comment: can you share code of your update method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `concatMap` operator inside of `chipAPI`.

something like:

```js
send$ = new Subject();

constructor(http: HttpClient) {
  this.send$.pipe(
    // contact waits until the inner stream has been completted.
    concatMap(([address, chips]) => this.http.post(address, chips).pipe(
      retry(5), // in case of failed request,
      // catchError(() => EMPTY), // perhaps we can ignore errors
    )),
    // takeUntil(this.destroy$), // you need to implement an unsubscribe trigger.
  ).subscribe();
}

update(address, chips): {
  this.send$.next([address, chips]);
}
```